# Find the Closest Value (Or Next Higher) In Column if a Parallel Column Contains a Certain Value

Tags: excel

How would I find the closest value in a column and if an exact match does not exist the highest closest value matches, but also the column to the right will contain the correct value?

http://postimg.org/image/wtuwe6nmx/

I need the value for b27 to match value to column b for count ratio when, the source rod depth (d27) and nuclear gauge serial number (e27).  If an exact match cannot be found in column b when the depth and serial number are populated then I would want it to choose the closest number that is no lower than the original number in b26.

Comment: You can add some sample data to your question: always better if your question is self-contained if possible.

Comment: It's not pasting correctly.. I will try to attach the excel..

Comment: It won't let me post the picture since i don't have a reputation.  I can share the excel if someone wants to help... thanks again.. I basically want to find the closest value in excel (search code b26) when a column value matches (d27 is the same as the value in a column d29:d5888), and another column value matches (e27 is the same as the value in a column e29:e5888).  Hope this helps.

Comment: *Edit your question* to add the sample data - don't use a comment.  You can use the "code block" formatting to format your data so it shows correctly. Or upload your screenshot to an image-sharing site and someone with higher rep may add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did that.  I am really stumped on this and just want the Count Ration (C/A) to pull so my data sheet will pull the correct density value from the nuclear gauge calibration table for soil compaction testing.